# Missing hd space on old Win2003 Std Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive

I have an Windows 2003 Std Server that is running AD/DNS/DHCP that is running out of hdd space on C: (70GB hd with two partitions (C=12gb,D=52gb))

Now I found a log file Symantec Reporting Agent that was 1.35gb
I shutdown the service, moved the log file to D (which has 50gb free) and then restarted the Reporting Agent service.

BUT when I check the hdd space on C: I only have 522MB free. (I was down to 120MB)
Whats up with that? A I losing my mind?

[image]

Comment: You'll need to do a little more research to find out where this is coming from. I use http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/ which helps track down where most of your space is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see how the file's colored blue?  That means it's compressed.  And most all text files compress pretty well, so I wouldn't be surprised if you were getting ~3:1 compression and the file size on disk was only ~400 MB.  You can verify this by right clicking, going to properties and checking the `size on disk` number.

Get yourself a tool like [Windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) and find out what's really using up your space.

Answer (score 1):

Was the log file in a compressed folder, i.e.: size on disk < actual size?

If you have the Win2k3 support tools installed (from the Windows media), you can use DIRUSE.EXE to see where your freespace is going.  It performs a similar role to **df** in Unix, e.g.:

```
diruse /m /* c:\
```

...and if that returns any large folders, have a nose in them, e.g.:

```
diruse /m /* "c:\documents and settings"
```